# Install SGE on ubuntu1604

Tags: ubuntu, sungridengine

I'm trying to install SGE on UBUNTU 1604.

After I ran the cmd

`sudo apt-get install gridengine-master gridengine-client`.

The progress is stuck at the last line of the screen shot

[image]

Only thing I can do is KILLING THE PROCESS to stop it. 
Does someone know what's going on after this log "Initializing spool (/var/spool/gridengine/spooldb)" ?

Thanks a lot